# change other app manifest Android

Tags: android

I want to write an android app to change the supports-screen of other app. How can I do that?

```
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" />
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Luckily, you cannot change stuff for different apps.

(Unless you have total control (codewise) of that app, so it reads stuff from a place another app can reach, but I doubt that from the information given).

Comment: Is that possible to do it through system setting?

Comment: What, taking control of the code of another app? certainly not. The answer is just a plain **no**.

Comment: I saw an app for Samsung Galaxy Tab and it is able to help other apps to display in full screen.

Comment: It is not possible to change the manifest of another app. That would be madness.

Comment: Understand it is not possible to change the manifest of another app. Maybe there is some global setting that can be made.